# File upload to cloudinary working fine locally but not in heroku in a laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5.1, cloudinary

I am working on a Laravel app which allows users to upload mp3 files which are stored in Cloudinary. Locally, uploading the files works fine but in Heroku I get a validation error that the file is missing. I can't really see why I am getting the validation error. I get this error when I try uploading a file that's still within the PHP max file upload limit i.e. 8.6MB. However, if I try uploading a file greater than 8.6 MB I get a Service Unavailable 503 error with -

> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to
>   maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later. What could be the problem?

This is the code to the store method in my Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title'         => 'required|min:3',
        'description'   => 'required',
        'channel'       => 'required',
        'podcast'       => 'required|size_format'
    ]);

    $data    = [
        'episode_name'          => $request->title,
        'episode_description'   => $request->description,
        'channel_id'            => $request->channel,
        'image'                 => self::DEFUALT_COVER_IMAGE,
        'audio_mp3'             => $this->upload->videoToCloudinary($request->podcast),
        'view_count'            => 0,
        'status'                => 0
    ];

    $this->episodeRepository->createEpisode($data);

    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Nice Job! ' . $request->title . ' is held for moderation.');
}
```

Comment: What is the max upload size for Cloudinary? Check with that might be they are not allowing to upload file greater than   8.6MB

Comment: Its 10MB for the free plan.....with 8.6 MB that's from heroku which I tried to increase by creating a custom.ini file then defining the max upload limit

Comment: Is this custom.ini file included in the main php.ini?

Comment: no its a separate file....found out that you can override settings in the php.ini by writting your own custom.ini....The settings in the custom.ini will be loaded instead of the default ones

Comment: What code do you have in videoToCloudinary function ?

Comment: `public function videoToCloudinary($podcast)
    {
        Cloudder::uploadVideo($podcast, null);
​
        return Cloudder::getResult()['url'];
    }`

Comment: I think you are uploading video file and you have used the key as 'audio_mp3' is this correct? Because by providing the mp3 file you are calling the uploadVideo method of Cloudinary

Comment: We're missing some more information here. What Cloudinary libraries are you using? When does the error occur? What's inside `$request->podcast`?

Comment: @AlankarMore I am using a package to do the uploading https://github.com/jrm2k6/cloudder. The 'uploadVideo' method serves both the video upload and audio upload the same way.

Comment: @NadavOfir the '$request->podcast' contains an Mp3 file attachment

Comment: @ChristopherVundi can you share the error response you're seeing?

Comment: I am getting a validation error that the podcast field is missing and a status 302. Just checked Heroku logs. Funny thing is everything works fine in development. I am confused why things won't work in heroku.